# выводятся только первые строки таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, table, redbeanphp

в БД есть таблица с данными продуктов из которых для каждого продукта должны выводиться определённые данные. Но в продуктах все данные повторяются

```php
    $length = R::count('products');

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "magnete");  

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `id` FROM `products`");
    $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $imgresult = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `image` FROM `products`");
    $ri = mysqli_fetch_assoc($imgresult);

    $nameresult = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `name` FROM `products`");
    $rn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nameresult);

    $priceresult = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `price` FROM `products`");
    $rp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($priceresult);

    $fromresult = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `from` FROM `products`");
    $rf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fromresult);

    $product1 = array(
        "name" => $rn['name'],
        "id" => $r['id'],
        "price" => $rp['price'],
        "image" => $ri['image'],
        "link" => $rf['from'],
        "category" => 'texnika'
    );
    $product2 = array(
        "name" => $rn['name'],
        "id" => $r['id'],
        "price" => $rp['price'],
        "image" => $ri['image'],
        "link" => $rf['from'],
        "category" => 'texnika'
    );
```

это данные о продуктах. В нём и нужно всё делать

```php
<?php for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { ?> 
    <div class="products">
        <img src=<?php echo '"'; print_r($product[$i]['image']); echo '"'; ?> >
        <h2><?php print_r($product[$i]['name']) ?></h2>
        <p><?php print_r($product[$i]['price']) ?></p>
        <button href=<?php echo '"'; print_r($product[$i]['from']); echo '"'; ?>>на сайт</button>
        <button href='product.php'>больше</button>
    </div>
<?php } ;?>
```

А это всё выводит на экран.

я пользуюсь redbean-ом.

Comment: весь ваш код можно переписать одной строчкой `$products = R::findAll('products');`

Comment: да я знаю но пока нужно чтобы всё было так. Да и при этом тоже будут видны только данные из первой строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто вы запрашиваете только первую строку результата. Чтобы вывести остальные строки результата надо делать что-то похожее

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
    while($rf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    }
}
```